# how to derive the condition for when $(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I encountered this in Spivak Calculus problem 16. I realize that the condition is $x=0=y=0$ for all even $n$ and $x=y=0$ and $x=-y$ for all odd $n$. However I'm not sure if there's a way to derive it through the given $(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n$

Comment: what does the question ask exactly? There are infinitely many solutions such as $(x,0)$ for any value of $x$

Comment: notice that $x=0$ alone is sufficient (like $y=0$)

Comment: I think you have not given the complete details, as for n=1 which is odd it still holds for all x and y.

Comment: Uhh, binomial theorem?

Comment: do you know any calculus? in particular, do you know how to study a function using derivatives?

Comment: $(x+y)^p \equiv x^p+y^p \pmod p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan $x,y$ are most likely real numbers

Comment: Also, for $n=0$ it never holds.

Answer (score 2):

$n=1$ trivially works for all $x, y$. Let's consider $n \geq 2$.

Dividing both sides by $x+y$, we define $a = \frac{x}{x+y}$. Then we wish to find solutions to
$$a^n + (1-a)^n = 1.$$

By taking a derivative, we obtain $na^{n-1} - n(1-a)^{n-1}$, which is zero only at $a = \frac 12$. So the function $f(a) = a^n + (1-a)^n - 1$ only has one turning point, and hence can only have two roots (since between any two roots there is a turning point).

But $a = 0, 1$ are clearly roots, and so they are the only such roots, and converting back gives that either $x$ or $y$ are $0$.

(Alternatively, under the restriction that $x, y$ are positive integers, observe that no solutions for $n \geq 3$ exist, by Fermat's Last Theorem.)

Comment: isn't $x=-y$ also true for odd $n$?

Comment: Yes, I realise I was working under the assumption that $|x|\neq |y|$, because you'd already solved that case. If $x=-y$, then dividing by $x+y$ is illegal which is why that solution doesn't turn up in this analysis.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have yet to find a method for showing $x=-y$, do you have any idea how it could be achieved?

Comment: To be more clear the solution I give above works whenever $x \neq -y$, so you just need to check manually to see when $x = -y$ works. In particular you need to solve the equation $(x + -x)^n = x^n + (-x)^n$, which is solvable iff $x = 0$ or $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

First off, for $n>0$:

$$(x+y)^n = x^n + y^n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {n \choose i} x^iy^{n-i} = x^n + y^n \implies \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{n \choose i}x^iy^{n-i} = 0$$

It is apparent that if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ the sum goes to $0$ because the argument of the summation will always have both $x$ and $y$ raised to a degree greater than or equal to $1$.

Now, there is a special case if $n$ is odd. Because you can pair terms:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{n \choose i}x^iy^{n-i} = \sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2}{n \choose i}(x^iy^{n-i} + x^{n-i}y^i) = 0 $$

so if $(x^iy^{n-i} + x^{n-i}y^i) = 0$ for all $i$ then their sum will also be $0$. This can be accomplished by setting $x = -y$, now:

$(x^iy^{n-i} + x^{n-i}y^i) = (x^i(-x)^{n-i} + x^{n-i}(-x)^i) = x^n1^{n-i}+x^n1^{i} = 0$

because if $n$ is odd, $1^i = -1^{n-i}$. Thus we have our condition. This is not a proof that there is not another condition, if that is something you also desire then let me know and I will update my post.

Comment: I don't understand how exactly you disintegrated that summation from $n-1$ to $(n-1)/2$

Comment: Because I took the first term and the last term of the series and paired them together then cut the bounds of the series by half.

Comment: This is the same concept as if you were to add up the numbers from 1...100 as follows: $1+2+...+99+100 = (1+100)+ (2+99)+...+(50+51) = 101*50 = 5050$