# If x and y are real numbers prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{n \choose i}x^iy^{n-i} = 0 \implies x=0,y=0$ or both for even $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If x and y are real numbers prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{n \choose i}x^iy^{n-i} = 0 \implies x=0,y=0$ or both for even $n$

Couldn't the terms just cancel each other out under special circumstances other than when $x,y=0$ ?

Comment: What is known about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: The statement is false for $n=3$. 

For $x = -y=1$, $3xy^2 + 3x^2y = 0$.

Comment: @Isomorphism I'm sorry I have edited the question.

Comment: If x and y can be complex, it is still wrong, try n=4.

Comment: @Isomorphism Can you help me rephrase the question in a way it makes sense?

Comment: Where did you get the question from? Write it exactly as given. I don't know what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Isomorphism  [From here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709233/how-to-derive-the-condition-for-when-xyn-xnyn)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually equivalent to $x^n + y^n=(x+y)^n$ by the binomial theorem, whence I will refer you to the answer to the [relevant question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709233/how-to-derive-the-condition-for-when-xyn-xnyn).

Comment: I am actually coming from that same question (which was posted by me too). I don't think it has the answer as to why above summation entails that result.

Comment: By the binomial theorem, $(x+y)^n - x^n - y^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} x^i y^{n-i} - x^n - y^n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i} x^i y^{n-i} = 0$. So $(x+y)^n = x^n + y^n$.

Comment: but does this necessarily infer that $x$ and $y$ be $0$?

Comment: @Richard: hdighfan has answered your question in the other post. You should ask for clarifications at that post.

Comment: @Richard Yes, by the answer given in the linked question.